# App crashes on trying to access elements from the cursor in onBindViewHolder()

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, cursor, simplecursoradapter

Here is my code

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyRecyclerViewForFav.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        data d = new data();

//        if(  cursor.moveToNext()  )
       // Log.d("this2",);
        cursor.moveToNext();
        Log.d("this2",cursor.getInt(1)+"");
        
        String temp = d.Convert(str, position);
        holder.textView.setText(temp);
        holder.rowNumber.setText((position + 1) + ".");
    }
```

if i print the size of cursor using getCount() it works fine but when trying to access the elements app crashes

Comment: please post your stack trace too

Answer (score 1):

Having `cursor.moveToNext()` in `onBindViewHolder()` does not make sense. It would only work if the user scrolled down, it won't work when the user scrolls up. Rather use `moveToPosition(position)`.